# Can't convert timestamp to a time zone Asia/Jerusalem

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, timestamp

I'm using Oracle and it doing:

```
 SELECT FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2017-03-31 02:10:00', 'Asia/Jerusalem') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Throws an:

```
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
```

But I don't know why. There's no time change on that day and DST time starts the 24 of March in 2017. Any idea?

Comment: Do you really mean it crashes? Or does it throw an error?

Comment: Yes, it throws an error, sorry. I added the details.

Comment: It's a problem specific to the hour of 2AM on that day where the TZR is Jerusalem. `TIMESTAMP '2017-03-31 01:59:59'` works just fine as does `TIMESTAMP '2017-03-31 03:00:00'` . Puzzling

Comment: @user8343746 Looks like a Standard oracle bug, quite a few people have faced this issue. you should check in [metalink](https://support.oracle.com/) for solutions. they have listed a few.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP '2017-03-31 02:10:00' at time zone 'Asia/Jerusalem'` works

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name aren't these two different ? `at time zone` will give me *GMT -> Local*, `FROM_TZ` will give me *Local -> GMT*

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your Oracle database thinks that the spring-forward DST transition in Israel for 2017 is on March 31st instead of March 24th.  This will happen if the time zone data file has not been updated.

The `Asia/Jerusalem` zone was last modified in tzdb version 2012h, when the relevant rule was changed from `Fri>=26` to `Fri>=23` in [this commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/ff07530c90837d8718ae420d1f085d2bfd17069a?diff=split#diff-cffe819d4413b95dd8c35c0085930789L1205).  Therefore, your database has data derived from a tzdb release *older* than 2012h.  The [2012h announcement](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2012-October/000006.html) references this change.

Oracle database has its own releases and versioning scheme for its time zone files, so I'm not sure exactly which Oracle tz data file version this would relate to.  However, you should consider it a best practice to always update your time zone data to the most current version.  Subscribe to the [tz announcements mailing list at IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), and then look for a corresponding update from Oracle shortly after each tzdb release.

For information about updating the time zone data in Oracle, look [in the documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG259).

(My understanding is that the Oracle time zone data files themselves are only available through Oracle with a valid support contract.)